# converting JavaScript countdown seconds in hours/mins/secs

Tags: javascript

I have to change the following code so that function createTimer gets two parameters (hours and minutes) and the output format has to  be "hours minutes seconds" and i am struggling to solve this.

```
function createTimer(options) {
  var timer,
    instance = this,
    seconds = options.seconds,
    updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function () {},
    counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function () {};

  function decrementCounter() {
    updateStatus(seconds);
    if (seconds === 0) {
      counterEnd();
      instance.stop();
    }
    seconds--;
  }

  this.start = function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = 0;
    seconds = options.seconds;
    timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
  };

  this.stop = function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}

function startTimer() {
  var timer = new createTimer({
    seconds: 10,
    onUpdateStatus: function (seconds) {
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds + " seconds";
    },
    onCounterEnd: function () {
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time's up";
    },
  });
  timer.start();
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Converting seconds to hours and minutes?

Comment: no, i have a problem using "hours and minutes" as parameters without changing the "startTimer" function. I mean, can i do that or i have to remake all the code? "Options" here is an object right? I'm beginner to this and i need some hints

Comment: Do you only have to change the output or do you need to change the input parameters, so that the `createTimer` function accepts hours and minutes instead of seconds?

Comment: Both. The output has to be "Hours minutes and seconds" and also createTimer function need to accepts hours and minutes as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep decreasing seconds, and use several if conditions to subtract one from minutes and hours.

```js
function createTimer(hours, minutes) {
  var timer,
    instance = this,
    seconds = 0,
    hours = hours,
    minutes = minutes,
    updateStatus = onUpdateStatus || function() {},
    counterEnd = onCounterEnd || function() {};

  function onUpdateStatus(h, m, seconds) {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = h + " hours " + m + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";
  }

  function onCounterEnd() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time's up";
  }

  function decrementCounter() {
    updateStatus(hours, minutes, seconds);
    if (hours === 0 && minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
      counterEnd();
      instance.stop();
    }
    seconds--;
    if (seconds < 0) {
      seconds = 59;
      minutes--;
      if (minutes < 0) {
        hours--;
        minutes = 59;
      }
    }

  }

  this.start = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = 0;
    seconds = seconds;
    timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
  };

  this.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}

function startTimer() {
  var timer = new createTimer(0,1);
  timer.start();
}

startTimer()
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: yea i thought about that, but still my function doesn't get "hours and minutes" as parameters. It still gets the "options" object as param

Comment: @chris09trt Check the updated answer.

Comment: still not good :D , forgot to say.... it has to get ONLY two params (hours/mins) not more. I can change whatever i want in createTimer function but not in startTimer. That's why i'm a little bit confused, it's a tricky problem

Comment: @chris09trt not even seconds param? If you want `createTimer` to accept only those two params, then you need to migrate the  `onCounterEnd` and `onUpdateStatus ` functions inside it from `startTimer`.

Comment: hm.... can you show me please? i am still confused :/

Comment: @chris09trt Check now..